# Focusing GeoNetwork default map on Canada?

Tags: geonetwork, default

When i open geonetwork "map", I want to see 'Canada' by default instead of other locations of the world. I changed the bounding box within an xml file located at
/usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/data/resources
I am not seeing the change in the map extent.

can anyone suggest whats wrong here?

Comment: Using GeoServer? > https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/users/quickstartguide/viewing/index.html [Geographic bounding box]

Comment: No using geonetwork I have to make change in the xml file so that default map is focused on canada when I first load the map. I need to make change in the geonetwork java code built

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the file [`config-viewer.xml`](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/master/web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/data/data/resources/map/config-viewer.xml). Usually this file is stored in the browser's local storage and it is not reloaded every time you access the webpage. Try to use an incognito window or to clear the storage after changing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bounding box settings in Admin Console --> Settings --> User interface tab.

Comment: I'm assuming you are referring to the _Viewer Map Configuration_? When I set these and save settings, nothing happens, so what is it you are suggesting?

Comment: Ok so things to check. If your Map projection is ESPG:3857. You can see this in the section above the Viewer Map Configuration. Then you need to set the coordinates to match the projection. For example on my setup. MinX =1830000 , MinY =-4140000, MaxX =3660000, MaxY =-2520000. Also make sure that the Layer objects in JSON is defined to something like this: {"type":"osm"}. I also went on to change the extent of the Search Map and Editor Maps.