# Changing the default GeoNetwork Map Viewer basemap (OSM) Center

Tags: geonetwork

By default, GeoNetwork Map Viewer renders the base OSM map at center 0 with zoom 2. I would like to change the center to a different point (like Paris) with a zoom of 6.

How to accomplish it by changing the 3.8.1 geonetwork core source directly?

From [mapsManager.js](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/3.8.x/web-ui/src/main/resources/catalog/components/common/map/mapsManager.js), I tried changing center and zoom to different value under:

```
createMap: function(type) {
          var config = gnMap.getMapConfig()['map-' + type];
          var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [],
            view: new ol.View({
              center: [0, 0],
              projection: gnMap.getMapConfig().projection,
              zoom: 2
            }),
```

I rebuilt the war and deployed it to app server, but it does not seem working.

Also saw the post on:
[Focusing GeoNetwork default map on Canada?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311803/focusing-geonetwork-default-map-on-canada). But not clear what exactly change to the [config-viewer.xml](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/3.8.x/web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/data/data/resources/map/config-viewer.xml)

Any insights?

Comment: did you try to edit the bounds of `<ows:BoundingBox crs="EPSG:3857">
      <ows:LowerCorner>-8604130.477526832 -320097.07393612247</ows:LowerCorner>
      <ows:UpperCorner>8948257.201654762 8720263.135408245</ows:UpperCorner>
    </ows:BoundingBox>` to match the extent of france?

Answer (score 1):

I found a easy way to set it (which was from the older 3.x release):

views/default/config.js

```
//comment out the viewerMap, define it explicitly using the customized maps config
//var viewerMap = gnMapsManager.createMap(gnMapsManager.VIEWER_MAP);
var mapsConfig = {
    center: [-39813045, 6213440],
    zoom: 4
};

var viewerMap = new ol.Map({
    controls: [],
    view: new ol.View(mapsConfig)
});
```